# Will converting my first partition to EXT4 make me lose boot info?

Tags: boot, ntfs, gparted, ext4

I recently switched from Windows to Lubuntu as my sole OS.

My filesystem now has a NTFS partition with all my data (which I now would like to convert to EXT4), a EXT4 partition with Lubuntu on it and a swap partition.

I have a full backup of the data, so wiping the NTFS partition is not the problem. But I want to be sure that, after wiping/converting it I can still boot Lubuntu just as before. The data partition is the first partition and gparted shows me a 'boot' flag on it.

Here is my boot info output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1548312/

Can I just delete the partition, and create a EXT4 one in it's place with gparted?

Would be great if someone with greater knowledge could have a look! :)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. As I found out, boot flags are a windows thing, so Ubuntu wouldn't bother about them in any way. Deleting the partition and recreating a EXT4 in it's place worked perfectly fine and didn't change anything in terms of booting the system.